# TreeGrid: setting data root has no effect

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I'm trying to setup a TreeGrid, my data object looks like this:

```
{
    "code": "success",
    "data": {
        "text": ".",
        "children": [
            {
                "clientname": "Market",
                "contact": "OpenX Market Advertiser",
                "email": "asdasd@asdasd222.de",
```

I need to tell Ext that it should use *data* as the root element:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    model: 'Task',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'http://localhost/rocketads/trunk/advertisers/index/stats:true/',
        reader:{
            type:'json',
            root:'data'
        }
    },
});
```

This doesn't work for me although I'm successfully using this with normal Stores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately with a TreeStore, whatever you use for root is also used as the root for each subsequent level, so it's probably finding the root node, then not finding its `data` property. Either change the top level property from data to children or change each instance of children to data.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have setup your reader with `root: 'data'` you have to replace 'children' with 'data' in your json:

```
{
    "code": "success",
    "data": {
        "text": ".",
        "data": [ // << not "children"
            {
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use this:

```
        reader: {
        type: 'json',
        // See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9159627/extjs-loading-tree-from-json-file-using-mvc
        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263380/extjs4-json-treestore
        root: function(o) {
            if (o.data) {
                return o.data;
            } else {
                return o.children;
            }
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in ExtJS 4.2
I try to solve this problem by following code.

```
Ext.define('XZSoftware.view.sysconfig.permission.PermissionWindow', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    itemid: "sysconfig-permission-window",
    vierConfig: { loadMask: true },
    layout:
    {
        type: "fit"
    },
    minWidth: 400,
    minHeight: 300,
    tree: null,
    treeStore: null,
    initComponent: function () {
        var me = this;
        Ext.log("initComponent()", me);

        me.treeStore = Ext.create("Ext.data.TreeStore", {
            proxy: {
                type: "ajax",
                actionMethods: { read: "POST" },
                reader: {
                    type: "json",
                    root: "data"
                },
                url: '/permissiontree_load.xzsoftware?o=AAAAACB'
            },
            root: {
                text: "Premission Tree",
                expanded: true
            }
        });

        me.tree = Ext.create("Ext.tree.Panel", {
            rootVisible: false,
            store: me.treeStore
        });

        me.items = [
            me.tree
        ];

        this.callParent(arguments);
    },

    Version: "1.0.0.0"

});
```

The JSON will be responsed from HTTP request.

```
{
    "total": 17,
    "data": [{
        "data": [{
            "data": [],
            "expanded": true,
            "leaf": "true",
            "checked": false,
            "text": "HSBC"
        }, {
            "data": [],
            "expanded": true,
            "leaf": "true",
            "checked": false,
            "text": "All IDoc"
        }, {
            "data": [],
            "expanded": true,
            "leaf": "true",
            "checked": false,
            "text": "ProCRM"
        }],
        "expanded": true,
        "leaf": "false",
        "checked": false,
        "text": "Application Portal"
    }, {
        "data": [{
            "data": [],
            "expanded": true,
            "leaf": "true",
            "checked": false,
            "text": "Order List"
        }, {
            "data": [{
                "data": [],
                "expanded": true,
                "leaf": "true",
                "checked": false,
                "text": "Report by monthly total"
            }],
            "expanded": true,
            "leaf": "true",
            "checked": false,
            "text": "Order Report"
        }, {
            "data": [],
            "expanded": true,
            "leaf": "true",
            "checked": false,
            "text": "Search"
        }],
        "expanded": true,
        "leaf": "false",
        "checked": false,
        "text": "CNMOT - OMS"
    }, {
        "data": [{
            "data": [],
            "expanded": true,
            "leaf": "true",
            "checked": false,
            "text": "Company"
        }, {
            "data": [],
            "expanded": true,
            "leaf": "true",
            "checked": false,
            "text": "Funcation Setting"
        }, {
            "data": [],
            "expanded": true,
            "leaf": "true",
            "checked": false,
            "text": "Menu Setting"
        }, {
            "data": [],
            "expanded": true,
            "leaf": "true",
            "checked": false,
            "text": "Page Setting"
        }, {
            "data": [],
            "expanded": true,
            "leaf": "true",
            "checked": false,
            "text": "Permission"
        }, {
            "data": [],
            "expanded": true,
            "leaf": "true",
            "checked": false,
            "text": "Roles"
        }, {
            "data": [],
            "expanded": true,
            "leaf": "true",
            "checked": false,
            "text": "Users"
        }],
        "expanded": true,
        "leaf": "false",
        "checked": false,
        "text": "System Setting"
    }],
    "success": true,
    "message": "Success"
}
```

Notes:
1.Should set root config in TreeStore.
2.The children field in JSON need change to the root config in proxy of store. In my sample "children" set as "data".