# Loading data from the json file into treepanel

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

> In my data.json file I have static data which is to be loaded in the treepanel.According to this link **[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9411201/treegrid-setting-data-root-has-no-effect)**, I have changed "children" to "data".But still I am not geting data in my tree panel grid.

**My data.json file**

```
      {
        "data":
            [
             {
               "App": "active"
               "iconCls":"task-folder",
               "expanded":"false",
               "data": [
                        {
                          "AppReport1": "active",
                          "leaf": "true"
                         }
                       ]
             }
           ]
        }
```

Here Is what I am doing:

```
    initComponent: function () {
    var me = this;
    Ext.log("initComponent()", me);

    me.treeStore = Ext.create("Ext.data.TreeStore", {
        proxy: {
            type: "ajax",
            model   : 'EPH.model.DBStatusModel',
            autoLoad: true,
            type: 'ajax',
            url:'app/data/data.json',
            reader: {
                      type: 'json',
                      root : 'data'
                    }

             },
             root: {
                   expanded: true
              }
      });
      this.down('treepanel').setRootNode(store.getRootNode());
```

}

> I think I have problem in my data.json file.Is it correct or do I need to change something.Please help me out resolving this issue.Thanks.

Comment: In the reference link the first _data_ appears to be JSON Object and in your JSON file is an JSON Array. Have you checked that?

Comment: @KiaMorot :Thanks.Please have a look,I have changed it.But I am getting only "App" getting displayed in my treepanel.It is not getting expanded.I mean it is not showing its child i,e "AppReport1".Please correct me if I am missing something.Thanks again.

Comment: The first _data_ in your JSON Object is still a JSON Array. Have a look at the link you provide. I think your _data_ should be an JSON Object.

Comment: @KiaMorot : But that is root which I have mentioned in the reader config.Iam getting the data,but only the first record,and not getting its child data.

Comment: that's how appears in the reference linK!

Comment: Please help me out resolve this.Still I am having problem

Answer (score 1):

Childen it's a important part of configuration for Node interface.

Sencha api: [children](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/#!/api/Ext.data.NodeInterface-cfg-children)

This config param say you what data root node has.

EDIT:

and what happend with "**defaultRootProperty**":

Sencha api: [treeStore](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/#!/api/Ext.data.TreeStore)

> For the tree to read nested data, the Ext.data.reader.Reader must be
>   configured with a root property, so the reader can find nested data
>   for each node (if a root is not specified, it will default to
>   'children'). This will tell the tree to look for any nested tree nodes
>   by the same keyword, i.e., 'children'. **If a root is specified in the
>   config make sure that any nested nodes with children have the same
>   name. Note that setting defaultRootProperty accomplishes the same
>   thing**.

Comment: :Yeps I know that,But according to the reference link,if root  is being used in the reader,same root should be used.Please have a look.Thanks

Comment: Still I am only able to see only "App" and its child is not getting displayed.

Answer (score 1):

In the reference link the first data appears to be JSON Object and in your JSON file is an JSON Array. I think this it should look.

```
 {
"data": //root
      {
        "data"://children
            [
             {
               "App": "active"
               "iconCls":"task-folder",
               "expanded":"false",
               "data": [
                        {
                          "AppReport1": "active",
                          "leaf": "true"
                         }
                       ]
             }
           ]
      }
}
```

Note: This code was taken from the original JSON file of the author.

Comment: :( Still I am not getting data in my treepanel.

Comment: Then is something else. I would check the documentation and examples again.